# How to check a list of lists against a list of lists and count their overlaps? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements, counter

I have one list `a` containing 100 lists and one list `x` containing 4 lists  (all of equal length). I want to test the lists in `a` against those in `x`. My goal is to find out how often numbers in `a` "touch" those in `x`. Stated differently, all the lists are points on a line and the lines in `a` should not touch (or cross) those in `x`.

**EDIT**

In the code, I am testing each line in `a` (e.g. a1, a2 ... a100) first against x1, then against x2, x3 and x4. A condition and a counter check whether the a's touch the x's. Note: I am not interested in counting *how many* items in a1, for example, touch x1. Once a1 and x1 touch, I count that and can move on to a2, and so on.

However, the counter does not properly update. It seems that it does not tests `a` against all `x`. Any suggestions on how to solve this? Here is my code.

**EDIT**

I have updated the code so that the problem is easier to replicate.

```
x = [[10, 11, 12], [14, 15, 16]]
a = [[11, 10, 12], [15, 17, 20], [11, 14, 16]]

def touch(e, f):
    e = np.array(e)
    f = np.array(f)
    lastitems = []
    counter = 0
    for lst in f:
        if np.all(e < lst): # This is the condition
            lastitems.append(lst[-1]) # This allows checking the end values 
        else:
            counter += 1
    c = counter
    return c

touch = touch(x, a)
print(touch)
```

The result I get is:

```
2
```

But I expect this:

```
1
2
```

Comment: We can't reproduce your results without `x` and `a`

Comment: The actual files are large, but I have added an example of what ```x``` and ```a``` look like.

Comment: Now, `touch(x, a)` gives `2`. No idea why are you referring to 'blowup' in a dataframe though. If you really want help, please write code that is easy to reproduce!

Comment: @Jorge: Apologies, you are right. Have updated the code and edited the question. Hope it is easier now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of what exactly is the result you expect, your example and description are still not clear. Anyway, this is what I guess you want. If you want more details, you can uncomment some lines i.e. those with `#`

```
i = 0
for j in x:
    print("")
    #print(j)
    counter = 0
    for k in a:
        inters = set(j).intersection(k) 
        #print(k)
        #print(inters)
        if inters:
            counter += 1
            #print("yes", counter)
        #else:
            #print("nope", counter)
    print(i, counter)
    i += 1
```

which prints

```
0 2

1 2
```

Comment: I guess the index 0 and 1 are confusing. So I have removed them from the expected output.